# Javascript display block display none

Tags: javascript

I know there are a lot of post like that but I didn't understand why my function doesn't work. I'm learning then I hope you will be gentle^^

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="BurgerMenu">
            <button onclick="menuBurger()">
                &#9776;
            </button>
        </div>

        <nav id="SecondNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#itineraires">Itinéraires</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trafic">Infos trafic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#actualite">Actualité</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Here is my CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 812px) { 
#FirstNav{
    display:none !important;
}

#sectionLogo{
    margin: 25px;
}

#secondHeader{
    display :flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline !important;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#BurgerMenu{
    display: block !important;
}

#SecondNav{
    display: none !important;
}
```

}

and here is my JS function

```
function menuBurger(){
var x = document.getElementById("SecondNav");
if (x.style.display === "none"){
    x.style.display = "block";
}else{
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

}

I can't change the !important in CSS because that doesn't work without.
Thx to explain.

Comment: That important is problem. Js display cannot replace with css important.

Comment: Perhaps you can change the class of the element? e.g. #secondHeaderB

Comment: I saw that, as I understood, the function works without the !important but if I didn't put this !important on #secondNav, it doesn't work as toggle...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `!important`. It is creating the problem along with `id` specifier. Use `toggle` to add or remove class as required

```js
function menuBurger() {
  document.getElementById("SecondNav").classList.toggle('toggleDisplay')
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {
  #FirstNav {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #sectionLogo {
    margin: 25px;
  }
  #secondHeader {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline !important;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
  #BurgerMenu {
    display: block;
  }
  .toggleDisplay {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="BurgerMenu">
  <button onclick="menuBurger()">
                &#9776;
            </button>
</div>

<nav id="SecondNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#itineraires">Itinéraires</a></li>
    <li><a href="#trafic">Infos trafic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#actualite">Actualité</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I can't because the burger logo disapear and the menu is displaying on my media querie.

Comment: must be dues to some not required css

Comment: After modifiing my css during more than an 1hour, the function works... Thx for your time dude :)